# Debugging "step over" takes much longer than "resume"

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

When I debug my app if I step over a line it takes about 10 seconds vs when I resume to next break point on the next line it only takes about 1 second.

For example.

```
10 MyObject obj = Dao.getAnItem(); // getAnItem makes a few database calls via Hibernate
11 some other code.
```

I have breakpoints on both lines 10 and 11.

When the program is debugged if I step over line 10 it takes about 10 seconds to return.
However, if I "resume" to the next breakpoint (i.e. line 11) then it only takes about 1 second.

Comment: That's kind of the nature of the beast.  If you're debugging a long-running task or operation, then it doesn't return all that quickly - a tactic I've used is to put the break point past a part that I know is relatively IO/CPU intensive (including calls to DAOs).

Comment: @Makoto ah you beat me by like second I almost typed what you had word for word before I hit enter.

Comment: I have the same issue, buy in my case of long time operation it takes avout 5 miniutes comparing to 1sec. It gets very annoying if I accidentally hit step over instead of inserting a breakpoin and hit resume....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your Dao.getAnItem() method doesn't return because of another breakpoint.

Or you should review your break point properties. **Try  change "Suspend JVM" to "Suspend Thread"** so your breakpoint on line 10 will never suspend your other threads. And let me the result.